# Android Chrome "auto dark mode for web content" ruins fine css

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, tailwind-css

I design a React page, using tailwind for CSS. On Android Chrome, the page's output is really awful for users who enable dark mode at the system level.

The worst thing is that I have designed a perfectly fine dark css solution (using "dark:" prefixes for classnames). It work fine on all devices, except chrome based browsers on Android.

When I disable Chrome's "auto dark mode for web content" feature, all is fine.

My tailwind.config.js starts with this:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,cjs,mjs}',
  ],
  darkMode: 'media',
  theme: {
     ...
```

My index.html contains the following tags:

```
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="white" />
    <meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" content="black" />
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
```

I thought this would indicate to Chrome that dark mode is taken care of... but no, and I do end up with black buttons and text on a black background.

What am I missing, any way to circonvert this thing? I am using tailwind 3.4.1 by the way.

Thanks!